# How to populate country-state-city drop-down in Contact From 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to populate all countries drop-down & respective states-cities in my contact form, I'm using `Contact Form 7`. How will I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. And read [mcve]. You will get more answers.

Answer (score 3):

Contact Form 7 doesn't have a country list by default. You need to populate all values by yourself.

As a starting point, this is a list of countries:

```
[select country "United States" "Canada" "Mexico" "United Kingdom" "-----" "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "American Samoa" "Andorra" "Angola" "Anguilla" "Antigua and Barbuda" "Argentina" "Armenia" "Armenia" "Aruba" "Australia" "Austria" "Azerbaijan" "Azerbaijan" "Bahamas" "Bahrain" "Bangladesh" "Barbados" "Belarus" "Belgium" "Belize" "Benin" "Bermuda" "Bhutan" "Bolivia" "Bonaire" "Bosnia and Herzegovina" "Botswana" "Bouvet Island (Bouvetoya)" "Brazil" "British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)" "British Virgin Islands" "Brunei Darussalam" "Bulgaria" "Burkina Faso" "Burundi" "Cambodia" "Cameroon" "Cape Verde" "Cayman Islands" "Central African Republic" "Chad" "Chile" "China" "Christmas Island" "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" "Colombia" "Comoros" "Congo" "Congo" "Cook Islands" "Costa Rica" "Cote d'Ivoire" "Croatia" "Cuba" "Curaçao" "Cyprus" "Cyprus" "Czech Republic" "Denmark" "Djibouti" "Dominica" "Dominican Republic" "Ecuador" "Egypt" "El Salvador" "Equatorial Guinea" "Eritrea" "Estonia" "Ethiopia" "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)" "Faroe Islands" "Fiji" "Finland" "France" "French Guiana" "French Polynesia" "French Southern Territories" "Gabon" "Gambia" "Georgia" "Georgia" "Germany" "Ghana" "Gibraltar" "Greece" "Greenland" "Grenada" "Guadeloupe" "Guam" "Guatemala" "Guernsey" "Guinea" "Guinea-Bissau" "Guyana" "Haiti" "Heard Island and McDonald Islands" "Holy See (Vatican City State)" "Honduras" "Hong Kong" "Hungary" "Iceland" "India" "Indonesia" "Iran" "Iraq" "Ireland" "Isle of Man" "Israel" "Italy" "Jamaica" "Japan" "Jersey" "Jordan" "Kazakhstan" "Kazakhstan" "Kenya" "Kiribati" "Korea" "Korea" "Kuwait" "Kyrgyz Republic" "Lao People's Democratic Republic" "Latvia" "Lebanon" "Lesotho" "Liberia" "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya" "Liechtenstein" "Lithuania" "Luxembourg" "Macao" "Macedonia" "Madagascar" "Malawi" "Malaysia" "Maldives" "Mali" "Malta" "Marshall Islands" "Martinique" "Mauritania" "Mauritius" "Mayotte" "Micronesia" "Moldova" "Monaco" "Mongolia" "Montenegro" "Montserrat" "Morocco" "Mozambique" "Myanmar" "Namibia" "Nauru" "Nepal" "Netherlands" "Netherlands Antilles" "New Caledonia" "New Zealand" "Nicaragua" "Niger" "Nigeria" "Niue" "Norfolk Island" "Northern Mariana Islands" "Norway" "Oman" "Pakistan" "Palau" "Palestinian Territory" "Panama" "Papua New Guinea" "Paraguay" "Peru" "Philippines" "Pitcairn Islands" "Poland" "Portugal" "Puerto Rico" "Qatar" "Reunion" "Romania" "Russian Federation" "Rwanda" "Saint Barthelemy" "Saint Helena" "Saint Kitts and Nevis" "Saint Lucia" "Saint Martin" "Saint Pierre and Miquelon" "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" "Samoa" "San Marino" "Sao Tome and Principe" "Saudi Arabia" "Senegal" "Serbia" "Seychelles" "Sierra Leone" "Singapore" "Sint Maarten (Netherlands)" "Slovakia (Slovak Republic)" "Slovenia" "Solomon Islands" "Somalia" "South Africa" "South Georgia & S. Sandwich Islands" "Spain" "Sri Lanka" "Sudan" "Suriname" "Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands" "Swaziland" "Sweden" "Switzerland" "Syrian Arab Republic" "Taiwan" "Tajikistan" "Tanzania" "Thailand" "Timor-Leste" "Togo" "Tokelau" "Tonga" "Trinidad and Tobago" "Tunisia" "Turkey" "Turkey" "Turkmenistan" "Turks and Caicos Islands" "Tuvalu" "U.S. Virgin Islands" "U.S. Minor Outlying Islands" "Uganda" "Ukraine" "United Arab Emirates" "Uruguay" "Uzbekistan" "Vanuatu" "Venezuela" "Vietnam" "Wallis and Futuna" "Western Sahara" "Yemen" "Zambia" "Zimbabwe"]
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/MatthewEppelsheimer/1498955

Comment: I got your reply to populate all county values in your shortcode. But I'm looking for the option that when a country will be selected from drop-down, only then respective states will  be visible & the same logic will go for cities as depending on the states.